# PHP debugging in XAMPP

Tags: php, debugging, xampp, wamp, xdebug

Is any debugger is installed by default in XAMPP/WAMP server or We have manually download and configure the debugger? Also do recommend the best PHP debugger.

Comment: I don't have details, because I haven't done php in months, but you can try NetBeans, I believe it supports PHP debugging with XAMPP.  Also supports PHPUnit very nicely too :)

Comment: @Zoidberg, yes NetBeans has a way to debug with xdebug and it can be configured/enabled in xampp.

Comment: When you say "the best debugger", are you willing to pay? As far as I know, Xdebug is the only free alternative.

Comment: @jlafay Sounds like it is something your currently using, you should put in an answer, you have a guaranteed upvote from me.

Comment: No I don't use Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Netbeans and Xampp with debugging, simply open **c:\xampp\php\php.ini** and add these rows. It worked for me like a charm.

```
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_port =9000
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

Or check this out: Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbJOP0YcSjs

Answer (score 1):

- No debugger is installed by default in xampp
- Yes, you've to manually configure it
- Use Xdebug debugger

## These steps worked for me. I'll describe my setup below

My setup: Win 10 Pro, XAMPP 7.3.33, IntelliJ IDEA

### Summary

#### Summary - Installation

1. Download xdebug DLL
2. put some lines in php.ini
3. Restart Apache

#### Summary - Usage

1. Put a breakpoint in your code
2. Start listening to debug connections on IntelliJ IDEA
3. The debugger will pause at the line when that particular line gets invoked by the server

### Details

All the details below have been taken from https://gist.github.com/odan/1abe76d373a9cbb15bed . All credit goes to them

## Installing Xdebug for XAMPP with PHP 7.x

- New: [XAMPP - XDebug Setup for PHP 8](https://odan.github.io/2020/12/03/xampp-xdebug-setup-php8.html)

### Requirements

- XAMPP for Windows: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
- [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

### Setup

If the file `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll` already exists, you can skip the download.

- Download Xdebug for the specific PHP version:

  - PHP 7.4 (64-Bit): https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
  - PHP 7.4 (32-Bit): https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.4-vc15.dll
  - PHP 7.3 (64-Bit): https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll
  - PHP 7.3 (32-Bit): https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.3-vc15.dll
  - PHP 7.2 (32-Bit): https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.2-vc15.dll
  - PHP 7.1 (32-Bit): https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.1-vc14.dll
  - PHP 7.0 (32-Bit): https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.0-vc14.dll
- Move the downloaded dll file to: `C:\xampp\php\ext`
- Open the file `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` with Notepad++
- Disable output buffering: `output_buffering = Off`
- Scroll down to the `[XDebug]` section (or create it) and copy/paste these lines:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;36000 = 10h
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

- Restart Apache
- Click the Github ★ Star button :-)

### PhpStorm

- Use the [PhpStorm bookmarklets generator](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) to activate Xdebug from the browser side.
- Enable the Xdebug option: "Can accept external connections". See [screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/781074/83182499-ba9e7f00-a126-11ea-88c0-f28d0cbff260.png)

### Netbeans

- Change the Netbeans debugging options: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/781074/39868196-c98f15a0-5458-11e8-8143-d8c44079e099.jpg
- Change the following key in php.ini: `xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"`

### Visual Studio Code

- [Installing XDebug on anything for VSCode in 5 minutes](https://technex.us/2020/06/installing-xdebug-on-anything-for-vscode-in-5-minutes/)
- Install the [PHP Debug Adapter for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug).
- [Debug PHP In VSCode With XDebug](https://www.codewall.co.uk/debug-php-in-vscode-with-xdebug/)

### Adobe Brackets

- Install the [PHP Debugger for Brackets](https://github.com/spocke/php-debugger).

### Sublime Text 2 and 3

- Install the [Xdebug Client Package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Xdebug%20Client)

### Start debugger from the console

Enter cmd:

```
set XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=xdebug"
php test.php
```

### Postman

Add `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` as query parameter to the url, e.g.

- http://localhost?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM

Follow me on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/dopitz) | [Blog](https://odan.github.io)